# Можно ли в python, имея базу Word2vec перед операциями с ней, проверить есть ли в ней определённое слово?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec

Можно ли в python, имея базу Word2vec перед операциями с ней, проверить есть ли в ней определённое слово?

Answer (score 0):

Если `word2vec` имеет такую же структуру, как и питоновский `dict`, то можно либо с помощью ключевого слова `in`, либо методом `get_vector(word)`. Последний должен извлечь либо вектор, либо нули.